# Retrieving the last 40 or some specific number of elements from array in MongodB

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm building a messenger app using React.js with Node.js in the backend as an API, Express.js, MongodB and Socket.io. I want to send only the recent 40 or some specific number of messages to the user on initial load and send the rest later when the user requests.

Here's the DM(Direct Message) Model:

```
const dmSchema = new Schema(
    {
        users: [
            {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'User'
            }
        ],
        messages: [
            {
                message: String,
                from: {
                    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                    ref: 'User'
                },
                recipient: {
                    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                    ref: 'User'
                },
                timestamp: {
                    type: Date,
                    default: Date.now
                }
            }
        ],
        lastSeenMessage: [
            {
                by: {
                    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                    ref: 'User'
                },
                messageId: String
            }
        ]
    }
);
```

How can I set a limit for the messages array in the mongoose find method, and I would also like to get some ideas on keeping track of the messages sent already and decide what messages to send next.

Thank You :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this -

```
db.collection.find({}, {messages:{$slice:[0, 20]}})
```

This will provide you messages from 0 to 20.

```
$slice:[SKIP_VALUE, LIMIT_VALUE]}
```

Here is the reference for the MongoDB Slice feature. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/